# Music from old Tom & Jerry episode

Tags: soundtrack, tom-and-jerry

I've searched for the names of the pieces from this episode:

for a couple of times in the past and accumulated quite a few hours trying to find out the names of those I don't recognize. Sadly, with no results.

- What are the names of the pieces in this episode?

What I already recognize:

- 1:17 - Beethoven's Moonlight Sonata
- 2:14 - Mozart's 11th sonata (Rondo alla Turca)
- 3:13 - Revealed to actually be Chopin's Nocturne Op. 9 *(thanks to Catija)*.
- 3:30 - Liszt's Liebestraum No3.

I believe some other parts are from Franz Liszt's Hungarian Rhapsody no. 2, but I'm not sure (they are used in one other episode so it's likely).

What I need help with:

- 0:36 - Mozart's Piano Sonata in D major - I. Allegro *(thanks to grej)*
- 2:03 - Debussy's Clair de Lune. *(thanks to Catija)*.
- 2:36 - Chopin's Militaire Polonaise *(thanks to grej)*
- 2:50 - Verdi's "Anvil Chorus" from the opera Il Trovatore *(thanks to Catija)*.
- 4:10 - Strauss - Blue Danube *(thanks to Catija)*.
- 4:32 - Schubert - Impromptu Op. 90, No. 3 *(thanks to Catija)*.
- 4:38 - Chopin's Militaire Polonaise *(thanks to grej)*
- 5:23 - Liszt - Hungarian Rhapsody No. 2 *(thanks to Catija)*.

Comment: Which **do** you recognize? Please state which you know and which you do not.

Comment: Oh god... Tom & Jerry Kids...

Comment: @Catija I first thought I'd write those that I do down, but then I realized it doesn't matter much.
Unless writing them is such a hard task... I'll go ahead and edit them in.

Comment: @SystemDown Nostalgia or mockery? Can't really get your meaning through text... :)

Comment: @Catija Oh, and by the way, it'll be kind of hard to state which ones I **don't** know...

Comment: But you can tell where they stop and start... anyway, that's a start for you. I'll try to keep figuring the ones out I missed.

Comment: @user2962533 - A bit of both I guess. Tom & Jerry Kids was a staple of my childhood. A hated one. :)

Comment: Why do people downvote without even giving a reason?...
How is this a bad question? Because instead of asking directly "what are the names of xyz?" I ask to give a list?

Comment: a long long time ago in a galaxy far away, music id questions were decided as off-topic because generally they don't add any appreciation or analysis of the work they appear in.

Comment: 3:30 is definitely the Liebestraum No 3.

Comment: @DForck42 Thank you. Although since I asked this, the "on hold" message appeared and directed me to the FAQ where I figured this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

0:36 - Mozart's *[Piano Sonata in D Major](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQMoIs6i6zE)*

1:15 - Beethoven's *[Moonlight Sonata](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4Tr0otuiQuU)*.

2:00 - Debussy's *[Clair de Lune](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CvFH_6DNRCY)*.

2:15 - Mozart's *[Rondo Alla Turca](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=quxTnEEETbo)*

2:35 - Chopin's *[Military Polonaise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24O-f7kv9aw)*

2:50 - Verdi's "[Anvil Chorus](https://youtu.be/c3x-pwJGsgU?t=1m7s)" from the opera *Il Trovatore*

3:14 - Chopin's *[Nocturne Op. 9, No. 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9E6b3swbnWg)*

3:30 - Liszt's *[Liebestraum No. 3 Love Dream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IKfe1TtBd6w)*

4:10 - Strauss' *[Blue Danube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CTYymbbEL4)*

4:31 - Schubert's *[Impromptu Op. 90, No. 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CyzUc2vC4JI)*

4:39 - Also Chopin's *[Military Polonaise](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=24O-f7kv9aw)*

5:27 - Liszt's *[Hungarian Rhapsody No. 2](https://youtu.be/LdH1hSWGFGU?t=9m11s)*

---

Thanks to [grej](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/20895/grej) for help with the Military Polonaise & Piano Sonata in D Maj.

Comment: You just made me **VERY** happy :D
I added the timings I'm missing (thank you for nudging to improve my question).
Do you by any chance recognize the one at the very beginning? 0:36?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it but I wasn't trying at that point yet, so I'll look at it later.

Comment: 2:35 and 4:39 is Chopin's Militaire Polonaise

Comment: @grej the irony... I knew I'd heard the 4:39 one recently. Thanks! I'm mobile right now but I'll add it when I get home.

Comment: 0:36 is Mozart's [Piano Sonata in D major - I. Allegro](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VQMoIs6i6zE)

Comment: Really not sure why someone would downvote this... Regardless of the question being off topic or not, there's nothing wrong with the answer.